# What are enemy power ups?

Tags: mechwarrior-2-31st-century-combat

While playing a mission, occasionally the computer voice in my Mech will state "enemy power up detected."  What are these power ups? Are they something on the map that I can steal for myself or is it simply indicating that the enemy Mechs have "powered up" in some way? I haven't been able to detect anything out of the ordinary when the computer voice says this, leaving me to believe that this is just for some immersion into the game.

Comment: My reading is that a new mech just, "turned on", ie. powered up, and you're being made aware of an additional threat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is kind of your second option. But not quite. It is not referring to a powerup such as some games have like a damage boost or overshield or such like. It is using "power up" to mean "turned on". A definition in the one online dictionary can be found here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/power%20up

So the voice is telling you that an enemy mech is powering up - that is that it has become operational. This warning means that you are likely to encounter that mech sometime soon.

Comment: +1 for this. If an Enemy is not active when you start the mission, and you are in range, you'll hear this cue when they activate their mech.